# About reference to enumii

Tags: enumerate, ref

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item\label{1}
    \item Second item\label{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First sub-item\label{2.1}
        \item Second sub-item\label{2.2}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Reference to First sub-item~\eqref{2.1}.
\end{document}
```

which produces the fooling output:

[image]

Is there a simple way to output just (a) as the reference?
That is, without reference to the `enumi` item.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
%\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\roman*)}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={(\alph*)},ref={(\alph*)}}



\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item\label{1}
    \item Second item\label{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First sub-item\label{2.1}
        \item Second sub-item\label{2.2}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Reference to First sub-item~\ref{2.1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @moewe Ohh, your absolutely correct. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: I'd probably also throw out the `\renewcommand` lines since they don't do anything useful any more.

Comment: @moewe done.  :)

Comment: Thank you @samcarter. But it's still producing 2a. I'd like it to produce (a).

Comment: And by some reason I don't know, actually it doesn't seem to read the `setlist` at all. I see this because it's now using the default values for enumeration: first arabic, second romanic

Comment: @amrsa Produces (a) for me

Comment: @amrsa Do you have these problems with the exact same code as in my answer or in your real document?

Comment: Previously, those `renewcommand` were working just fine. The only issue was that I didn't want the reference to use `enumi`as a prefix to `enumii`. But with those lines commented, the example just produces the standard output, with enumi=arabic, enumii=roman and the same issue with the reference. So it just ignores those lines with `\setlist`. I might have to check if there is some missing package, which I suppose would be the `enumitem`

Comment: I was able to make it work, by replacing `\setlist[enumerate,1]` with `\setenumerate[1]`, with the same arguments and likewise for the other line. Your answer was still useful, as it lead me to this change. Thanks.

Comment: @amrsa Please note that according to the package documentation `\setenumerate` is deprecated

Comment: Ok, so I suppose the problem is that I have a very old tex distribution and old version of the package (2.2, 2009). I'm using TeXShop 2.46 which I believe is from 2011. And I think I had problems once I tried to install a new version, probably because the computer is also very old (2006) and many recent programs don't run on it. `\setenumerate` seems not to be deprecated in this version, and perhaps `\setlist` doesn't do what you get in your computer...

Comment: @amrsa Ah, that explains your problems. Current enumitem version is `3.5.2`